# Visualize Spatial Data in Reporting Service

Tags: sql-server, geometry, spatial-database

Is it possible to visualize a piece of geographical map from SQL server Spatial data (geometry, not geography) in a report from reporting service? If yes, how should it be done in a course of action.

A concrete example is to display the orange line from the Chinese subway's map in a specific reporting page.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide any more specifics to help guide answers? For example, how are you generating your report currently?

Comment: Today, I don't have created a prototype yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use the advice given at the following address.  Pay special attention to the part where it says 'Do NOT use the wizard'.  Because do not use the wizard.  no.

http://geekdeck.com/create-a-map-report-using-spatial-data-in-sql-server-2008-r2/

To summarize (Thanks Get Spatial!):

1. Create a new Report Server Project
2. Create a new report.
3. Drag a Map item from the Toolbox to the Design surface.
4. Select SQL Server spatial query and click Next
5. Select the Add a new dataset with SQL Server spatial data and click Next.
6. Click New, then:

   a. Set the data source’s name.

   b. Click Edit to open the Connections Properties dialog. Set the server name to “YourServer”” server alias and enter a Database Name.
7. In the Design a Query step, type a T-SQL statement which returns the route you are interested in.  "Select X, Y FROM TableName WHERE RouteID = orangerouteID"

Comment: +1 - For a potential solution.  Welcome to GISse!  One thing that might be useful when you answer questions with a link to a more complete answer is to give a summary of what is in the link, in the answer here.  This can be useful in the event that a link is invalidated or changed for some reason.  If there is some detail about the answer, it may make it easier for someone to still be able to utilize the answer, or search for it and find it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, depends on how you're hosting and serving you're service and how you are doing overlays of the orange line.

Comment: perhaps you could expand your answer to be more helpful.  I doubt the OP actually wants to know if it is possible, but rather, how to actually do it.

Comment: If possible, I would like to read about how to do it.